# How to add JLabel to JEditorPane?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jlabel, jeditorpane

I am trying to extend the StyledEditorKit in Swing to be able to include a JLabel inside the editor. I was able to do that and this is what I got so far. In the image below, the highlighted text *button* is of type JLabel whereas the rest of the text is normal text.

[image]

As you can see the label renders a little below than the normal text. How do I align its top with top of the remaining text?

Here is the code for the view that is used to create this label element:

```
class ComponentView(Element elem) {
      @Override
      protected Component createComponent() {
        JLabel lbl = new JLabel("");
        lbl.setOpaque(true);
        lbl.setBackground(Color.red);
        try {
               int start = getElement().getStartOffset();
               int end = getElement().getEndOffset();
               String text = getElement().getDocument().getText(start, end - start);
               lbl.setText(text);
         } catch (BadLocationException e) {}
         return lbl;
       }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adjusting `Component.getAlignmentY` that controls the positioning of component relative to the text baseline as suggested in [ComponentView](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/ComponentView.html).

You could also try using `JTextPane` that provides easier support for embedded components. Components can be added using [insertComponent()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html#insertComponent%28java.awt.Component%29) method. Here is an example, it also demos `setAlignmentY`:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TextPaneDemo {
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        final JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();
        pane.setText("Some text");

        JButton buttonButton = new JButton("Insert label");
        buttonButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                JLabel label = new JLabel("label");
                label.setAlignmentY(0.85f);
                pane.insertComponent(label);
            }
        });

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(buttonButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        panel.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(400, 200);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```