# JLabel not in line with text in J

Tags: java, swing

I have this wierd irritating situation. I have a JTextPane with text inserted. Alogn with text, there are also Links as JLabels. Below is a snapshot:
 [image]

Now the issue is: Why is the JLabel (A HTML Link) not parallel with the text on the same line? It is slightly below.
Text is "Calibri" and Font 14. JLabel:

```
label.setForeground(Color.blue);    
label.setFont(new Font("Check",Font.BOLD,14));                
makeLinkable(label, new LinkMouseListener());
```

Please help. The link behind JLabel is: `<html><a href="file:///C:/Users/Jatin/Documents/NetBeansProjects/ImageRename/log/2012-10-5%20Time%2013-52-1.csv">
file:///C:/Users/Jatin/Documents/NetBeansProjects/ImageRename/log/2012-10-5%20Time%2013-52-1.csv</a></html>`

Comment: Looks like mentioned html is not the same as on your snapshot. The value in `a` tag on snapshot is `2012-10-5 Time 13-52-1`, but not `file:///C:/Users/Jatin/Documents/NetBeansProjects/ImageRename/log/2012-10-5%20Time%2013-52-1.csv`.

Comment: it is basically the same, just the text is different. Pic taken from different run. Thanks.

Comment: Then, probably it is layout problem. Can you provide simple example to run?

Comment: Actually it looks like there is `<br>` tag in html code

Comment: See also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13219158/230513).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at JComponent#setAlignmentY(...): [java - How to appropriately adding JLabel to JEditorPane? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12151158/how-to-appropriately-adding-jlabel-to-jeditorpane)

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class BaselineTest {
  public JComponent makeUI() {
    JLabel label1 = makeLabel();
    JLabel label2 = makeLabel();
    String s = "For detailed infomation refer: ";
    JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
    textPane.replaceSelection(s);
    textPane.insertComponent(label1);

    Dimension d = label2.getPreferredSize();
    int baseline = label2.getBaseline(d.width, d.height);
    label2.setAlignmentY(baseline/(float)d.height);
    textPane.replaceSelection("\n\n"+s);
    textPane.insertComponent(label2);

    return new JScrollPane(textPane);
  }
  private static JLabel makeLabel() {
    JLabel label = new JLabel("2012-10-05");
    label.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
    label.setOpaque(false);
    return label;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }
  public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(new BaselineTest().makeUI());
    f.setSize(320, 240);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```